# How can you accumulate values and emit it in Kotlin Flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a flow of integers and I want to accumulate them in a list. When the list has a specific size, the list should be emitted further.
This kind of works with `runningFold`, but the problem is that the list isn't recreated when it's already full. (see code below)

So basically I want to convert the input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] into [1,2,3,4,5] and [6,7,8,9,10]

I know, it is possible by just clearing the list once it has a size of 5, but this isn't very nice imo.

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
   fun main() = runBlocking {
        launch {
            repeat(20) {
                emitValue(it)
            }
        }

        flow
            .collect {
                // it should be of type Result
                println(it)
            }
    }


    private val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

    val flow = sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()
        .onEach { println("received: $it") }
        .runningFold(mutableListOf<Int>()) { list, value ->
            list.add(value)
            list
        }
        .filter { it.size >= 5 }
        .map {
            val result = Result(it.toList())
            it.clear() // that isn't very nice
            result
        }

    suspend fun emitValue(value: Int) {
        sharedFlow.emit(value)
    }

    data class Result(val list: List<Int>)
```

Comment: Why don’t you like calling clear? That’s basically how Iterable.windowed does it if you look at the source code. I personally would feel more comfortable implementing this in a flow builder than a chain of flow operators, but that’s a matter of opinion.  Your asSharedFlow call is useless since you follow it up with other flow operators that turn it into a cold flow.

Comment: I simplified the example a bit. In my use case it's another more complex data object than a list. That's also the reason why I jused the sharedFlow here. And I also have to somehow clear that data object as well, which is more complex. And still - I would like to have a solution where the list (in that example) is always created once "enought" data is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this more imperatively using the `flow` builder, which might be more suited to whatever more-complex problem you have than simple Lists. Example:

```
val blockSize = 5
val flow = flow<List<Int>> {
    var accumulator = ArrayList<Int>(blockSize)
    sharedFlow.collect {
        accumulator.add(it)
        if (accumulator.size == 5) {
            emit(accumulator)
            accumulator = ArrayList<Int>(blockSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the `asSharedFlow()` in your code doesn't accomplish anything, because once you use any Flow operator on the SharedFlow, the resulting Flow is not a SharedFlow. If you want the final result to be a SharedFlow, you will have to use `shareIn` on the final flow result. What you currently have is a cold flow that, each time it is collected, begins collecting from the SharedFlow under the hood.

Comment: Yes thx that would work. 
One question - I'd like to have something like:
I want to offer a flow (with the accumulated values) and some other classes can "subscribe" on them. So whenever a value is emitted, the subscribers are "notified". That would work with your solution - right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, because that just sounds like how every flow works and is the whole purpose of having a flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the flow to a list and chunk it. Not sure about the performance though.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val flow = (1..8).asFlow() // Assuming you have a flow emitting integers
    val chunkSize = 3 // Define the size of each chunk
    val result = flow.toList().chunked(chunkSize)
    println(result) // Prints [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
}
```

Comment: That would ofc work, but the result should still be a flow of type Flow<Result>. And the "emitting" process should still work

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of letters from a to d. Here we wait for the inner flow to complete and then after emit the outer one.

```
val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")

flow {
    var accumulator = ""

    letters.asFlow().flatMapMerge { letter ->
        flow {
            delay( Random.nextLong(10, 100) )
            emit(letter)
        }
    }.onEach {
        accumulator += it + ","
    }.lastOrNull()

    emit(accumulator)
}.collect {
    println("result $it")
}
```

The result comes in different orders each time

```
result c,d,a,b,
```